# Add Custom UIButton Programmatically fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm creating a custom round UIButton with following code. I want to add this UIButton programmatically. iOS crashed when I try to do that. It work fine in InterfaceBuilder.

Xcode give me this error.

> fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

What should I do to fix it? Any suggestion would be really appreciate.

Here is the code that I use for Round UIButton.

```
    import UIKit

    @IBDesignable
    class RoundButton: UIButton {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            setupView()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        initWithCoder
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            setupView()
        }

        override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
            super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
            setupView()
        }

        func setupView() {
            let radius = self.frame.size.height / 2
            layer.cornerRadius = radius
        }

    }
```

Comment: You got a `fatalError` in your `init(coder: )`. Swift is only doing its job

Comment: What should I put inside "required init?" ?

Comment: ...Something that doesn't raise an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd avoid the initializers altogether:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        setupView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        let radius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
    }
}
```

Something like that should work. You call `setupView` from `awakeFromNib` so I don't think there is any need to call it from inside the initializers.

If there is a reason why you need to write your own version of `init(coder:)`, then something as simple as this may work:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}
```

Comment: I try remove the initializers as you suggest but the button wouldn't get the  round treatment. will try the init(coder:).

Comment: Check my edit, too. I changed the `init(coder:)` to include the call to `setupView`. I forgot to put that in, initially. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by add `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` inside `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` without the `setupView()` I still need to have `override init(frame: CGRect)` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder serializes your storyboard and unpack it when your app run. It will always call `init(coder: )` you need to implement it:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // If your subclass has extra properties, initialize them here...
    self.property1 = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("property1")
    self.property2 = aDecoder.decoddeObjectForKey("property2") as! String
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.